# How to have frequency in Hz in Sine Wave block in Simulink?

Tags: matlab, simulink, frequency, trigonometry

I'm new to simulink. I have this "Sine Wave" block. And When I double click it, I get the frequency in (rad/sec) rather than in Hz.

***How can I change this to get the frequency in Hz?*** I searched in all Properties (right click then properties), but I can not find any way to change it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Enter the value in hertz and multiply it by 2*pi
like  for example

```
Value = 10000;
```

In block write

```
(Value)*(2*pi)
```

and the value in rads/s is calculated

Comment: I know about this, but I'm asking whether I can enter directly in Hz.

Comment: You can intilize your variable in an m file with an input of frequncy in hertz divide it by 2*pi , lets say foo = value/(2*pi) and enter foo in the sinwave block

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I know about that as well. I'm just wondering if this (rad/sec) can be changed to (Hz).

Comment: @KhaledMaged There is no way to enter the frequency in Hz.  Why are you opposed to converting your frequency into rad/s before entering it in?

Comment: Umar, you need to MULTIPLY by `2*pi` to convert from Hz to rad/s not divide.

Comment: Sorry my bad I mixed up , Thanks for the correction btw :)